# Creating an artistic bottle shaped like an ice cube or just having an asymmetrical shape

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, geometry-nodes

I'm new to Blender and I'm trying to create an artistic bottle shaped like an ice cube or just having an asymmetrical shape. A little like these examples:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I followed some tutorials to learn how to create regular bottle designs. But after some tryouts to deform the created bottles I realized that there must be a more efficient and easier way to create those kind of bottles from scratch.

I guess a good design could be done with using geometry-nodes but I never used geometry-nodes. I only watched some tutorials and saw geometry-nodes doing some crazy stuff within just a few steps.

Does anyone have a good and easy method for creating those kind of bottles?

Comment: Hello, I would say subdivide it enough and sculpt it?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Could you give me an example of how to do so? Do you think of an already created bottle, or a cube with dimensions set?

Comment: Yes a cube that you scale X 2 on Z, create an horizontal edge loop at it middle, select all and right click > subdivide enough, switch to Sculpt mode and use some brushes to deform. Then give it a glass material?

Comment: Okay, I will give it a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Create a cube, scale it X 2 on Z, create an horizontal edge lopp:

[image]

Right click > *Subdivide* to give it more topology:

[image]

Back in *Object* mode, rick click > *Shade Smooth*, and switch to *Sculpt* mode, begin to sculpt the way you want. You can keep the default brush (*Draw*), if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and left click it will invert the effect, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> left click will smooth:

[image]

At the end if you want to give it thickness select all and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normals*. Also give it a glass material.

Comment: Very cool. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the "few Steps", the problem in this mod is the bottleneck. The main idea here is conserve the same amount of point through a boolean:

[image]

Be aware that the order you plug in the `Join Geometry` will impact the storage of your data as we reuse it with the `Index` `Compare`.

The following consist in displacing the mesh except the bottleneck and create the interior.

[image]

Next you can make a thread and add it through another `Boolean Mesh` and `Subdivide Surface` the all thing.

[image]

The result:

[image]

I hope,it help ;D

[image]

Comment: Wow, now that's pretty amazing! Thanks a lot! I will give it a try...

Comment: It all ready pretty advance, but step by step I am sure you can ;D

Comment: It's really pretty advance... I think It will need some time to figure it out. :-)